# Migrate time machine data stored on external server (DROBO) onto new iMac 3.2Ghz

Tags: time-machine

I was hoping this was going to be easy :)
I have tried using the migration assistant but it can't seem to locate my server (DROBO fs) which has my time machine back up from my old mac book pro, i'd like to migrate my movies and photos onto my new iMac 3.2Ghz. My server is connecting to the iMac but the migration assistant can't see it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might need to force Time Machine to browse for backups on unsupported volumes (ie Drobo)

1. Open Terminal
2. type the following command

defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1

In case you cannot access the terminal during the first startup, create a dummy user (you don't want to duplicate the username in you backup), then open terminal, do the magic trick and start Migration Assistant from Applications/Utilities/